# How do I set the background position and size of a background image I set with setBackgroundBrush?

Tags: qt, qt4

I used Qt's setBackgroundBrush function to set a background image. How do I resize the image or set it's position?

For example, I'd like it to be centered and for it to fill the entire region.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with `setBackgroundBrush`, but you can also set background image with style sheets if you want more control. Sample code from Qt docs:

```
QLabel {
    background-image: url(dense6pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-xy;
}
```

More info available [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties).

Comment: Cool. Can you provide a small example or a link? I'm new to Qt. :D

Comment: I don't see a property to scale the background. The background is smaller than the viewport. It'd be nice to make it expand to fill the viewport. Is that possible?